# Determine all the roots of the equation given by $z^2(1-z^2)=16.$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

For my third year Complex variable  course, the question is

> Determine all the roots of the equation given by
>   $$z^2(1-z^2)=16.$$

My attempt: 
Let $z^2 = x$
$x(1-x) = 16$
$x-x^2 = 16$
$x^2-x-16 = 0$
$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 -4(16)}}{2}$
$x = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{-63}}{2}$
$x = \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{63}}{2}$
$z^2 = \frac{1 \pm i\sqrt{63}}{2}$

Am I correct so far?

BTW the question is worth $5$ marks.

Comment: looks correct to me now you need to find $z$ do you know how to do that

Comment: @MRK  thanks, finding the square root I guess.

Comment: Use `$\pm$` to show $\pm$. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Remember it is a fourth order equation, so the complete solution has four roots, in this example they occur in complex-conjugate pairs.